# Matplotlib axes formatter is not working correctly in Seaborn Stripplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

For some reason, when I try to use a [matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter) to reformat the x axis of a seaborn stripplot, it reformats the positions instead of the labels, MWE below. Using the same formatter function on a normal matplotlib scatterplot works fine, and gives the expected result.

There's also something else I don't understand about how the labels work, because printing one from each axis shows the same thing for the default and reformatted stripplots, which does not match the figure, and then gives an empty string for the scatterplot label...

```
 original stripplot label: Text(3, 0, '0.3')
 reformatted stripplot label: Text(3, 0, '0.3')
 reformatted scatterplot label: Text(0, 0, '')
```

```
import seaborn as sns   
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': np.random.randint(0,10,size=100) / 10, 'y': np.random.normal(size=100)})

fig, axarr = plt.subplots(3,1)
sns.stripplot(data=df, x='x', y='y', ax=axarr[0])
axarr[0].set_title('stripplot, default formatting')
print(f' original stripplot label: {axarr[0].get_xticklabels()[3]}')
      
sns.stripplot(data=df, x='x', y='y', ax=axarr[1])
axarr[1].xaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.FuncFormatter(lambda x, pos: f'{x:.2f}'))
axarr[1].set_title('stripplot, incorrect formatting')
print(f' reformatted stripplot label: {axarr[1].get_xticklabels()[3]}')

axarr[2].scatter(df.x, df.y, s=10, alpha=0.5)
axarr[2].xaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.FuncFormatter(lambda x, pos: f'{x:.2f}'))
axarr[2].set_title('scatterplot, correct formatting')
print(f' reformatted scatterplot label: {axarr[2].get_xticklabels()[3]}')

fig.tight_layout()
```

[image: example output image]

Comment: Seaborn's `stripplot` (as well as e.g. `barplot` or `boxplot`) always create a categorical ax, not a numerical ax. Therefore, a numerical formatter won't work.  Instead, you can manually convert the `x` column to the desired strings.  Also note that numerical data can be problematic for categorical plots; e.g. `0.1999....` will be put in a different slot than `0.2`, while that wouldn't form a problem for a scatter plot. Note that starting with seaborn 0.13, you can use `native_scale=True` to have a numerical axis for the `stripplot`.

Comment: The numerical x-axis of `sns.scatterplot` (as well as `sns.stripplot(...., native_scale=True)`) by default uses the `MaxNLocator` with 10 positions. You can change the locator with e.g. `ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(0.1))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use `native_scale=True` to preserve the number-ness of the data on the x axis:

```
sns.stripplot(data=df, x='x', y='y', native_scale=True, ax=axarr[1])
```

[image]

This feature is [new in 0.12.0](https://seaborn.pydata.org/whatsnew/v0.12.0.html#modernization-of-categorical-scatterplots) for strip/swarmplot, and [new in 0.13.0](https://seaborn.pydata.org/whatsnew/v0.13.0.html#support-for-numeric-and-datetime-data) for other categorical functions.

Comment: Thanks! For future people, also check out the comments by @JohanC above for more info